# CS50 blur function in pset4 filter-less not working

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote this code to blur an image in cs50 filter-less ps4 problem. It's not working, I can't find the problem. The way the code works is we check where the pixel-box is positioned. If it is at the corners we take the four boxes that do not go outside the picture, sum their RGB values separately and average them afterwards, If it is at the edges we take the six boxes that do not go outside the picture, sum them and average them afterwards, otherwise if it is in the middle of the picture take the nine boxes surrounding the pixel (itself included), sum their RGB values separately and take their average. As we do we keep assigning the resulting RGB values to the pixel separately.

```c
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
//Copying the image into a temporary image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //Blurring the Top Edge except for the corners
            if ((i = 0 ) && (j != 0) && (j < (width - 1)))
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6.0);
            }
            //Blurring the bottom Edge except for the corners
            else if ((i = height - 1) && (j != 0) && (j < (width - 1)))
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6.0);
            }
            //Blurring the left Edbge boxes except for the corners
            if ((j = 0 ) && (i != 0) && (i < (height - 1)))
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j +1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j +1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j +1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6.0);
            }
            //Blurring the right Edge boxes except for the corners
            else if ((j = width - 1 ) && (i != 0) && (i < (height - 1)))
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j -1].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 6.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j -1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 6.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j -1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 6.0);
            }
                //Blurring upper left corner
            else if ((i = 0 ) && (j = 0))
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j+1].rgbtRed) / 4.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j+1].rgbtGreen) / 4.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j+1].rgbtBlue) / 4.0);
            }
            //Blurring Upper right corner
            else if ((i = 0) && (j = width - 1))
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4.0);
            }
            //BLurring bottom left corner
            else if ((i = height - 1) && (j = 0))
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4.0);
            }
            //BLurring bottom right corner
            else if ((i = height - 1) && (j = width - 1))
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][1 - j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][1 - j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][1 - j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4.0);
            }
            //BLurring inner boxes
            else
            {
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 9.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 9.0);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round((image[i][j -1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 9.0);
            }
        }
    }
//Replacing the origional image with a blurred one
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
```

In response to this question. I managed to write a piece of code that actually worked. Below is the function defination of the function that adds the pixels.

```
    for (int a = (i - 1); a < (i + 2); a++)
    {
        for (int b = (j - 1); b < (j + 2); b++)
        {
//Checking if the pixel is part of the picture before adding its value
            if (a >= 0 && a < height && b >= 0 && b < width)
            {
                if (strcmp(colour, colour_red) == 0)
                {
                    sum += image[a][b].rgbtRed;
                }
                else if (strcmp(colour, colour_green) == 0)
                {
                    sum += image[a][b].rgbtGreen;
                }
                else if (strcmp(colour, colour_blue) == 0)
                {
                    sum += image[a][b].rgbtBlue;
                }
//counter is used to count number of summed pixels
                counter ++;
            }
        }
    }
//This piece of code helped clear the clutter and it worked just fine
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly means "It's not working"? Do you get an error message? Wrong results? Show the input you use, the output you get and if if it's not obvious explain why it's wrong.

Comment: _"It's not working, I can't find the problem."_  does not meet any threshold for a [valid question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  If you are in a CS50 class, and writing code to blur, then you should be well past being introduced to at least simple debugging techniques.  Step though your code in debugging mode, or use in-line `printf` statements to allow yourself to observe and identify unexpected values for intermediate results.  If you still have not figured it out, then at least you can post your findings in more detail.

Comment: `if ((i = 0 )` This is an assigment, not a comparison. Doesn't your compiler raise an eyebrow on that?

Comment: Not related: You overwrite each value of `temp` in your loops. There is no need to copy the array first. That's a waste of time.

Comment: @Gerhardh most compilers I know will not issue a warning for the assignment if you surround it in an extra set of parentheses. So `if (i = 0)` will be a warning, `if ((i = 0))` will not.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I assumed that only applied to the pattern `if ((i=foo())==something)` but now that you mention it, it may well be for all extra parentheses.

Comment: You are supposed to respond to comments. Please provide requested information and give feedback to suggestions/findings.

Comment: The main problem i realised was that i used assignments instead of comparisons thanks to @Gerhardh. I fixed it and now when i am runninng it, i get a segmentation fault. I am trying to debug it as ryyker advised. I want to reduce it also using loops.

Comment: Running the code in a debugger should quickly lead you to the place where that segmentation fault happens. Inspect your index values. I would especially look at the final `else` part. Are there any combinations of out of range index values that you don't catch with those `if`s before?